# Printing a text file (C++)

Tags: file, text, printing

I'm having trouble printing a text file, this is what I have to print

```
Michael 33 76 81
Brenda 44 79 90
Alex 79 88 70
Brian 82 93 50
Kevin 77 73 80
```

and this is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
struct STUDENT
{
    string   name;
    int      Exam1;
    int      Exam2;
    int      Exam3;
};
STUDENT S[5];
int main()
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open("data.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        f.getline(S[i].name,5,'\n');
        f>>S[i].Exam1>>S[i].Exam2>>S[i].Exam3;
        cout<<S[i].Exam1<<S[i].Exam2<<S[i].Exam3<<endl;

    }
    f.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

when I run my program it only prints a row of zeros

Comment: It looks to me like you are forgetting to read in the name... assuming that the input file looks like you want the output to look (you didn't say...)

Comment: yeah I want my input and output to look the same

Comment: I still get the same thing
000
000
000
000
000
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: OK - see my answer. Your `getline` statement was not right.

Answer (score 0):

You need a small change to the way you read the name - and you need to remember to print it, as well as spaces!

```
for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
{
    getline(f, S[i].name, ' ');  // <<<< only read up to the space, not the end of line
    f>>S[i].Exam1>>S[i].Exam2>>S[i].Exam3;
    cout<<S[i].name<<" "<<S[i].Exam1<<" "<<S[i].Exam2<<" "<<S[i].Exam3<<endl;

}
```

My entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
struct STUDENT
{
    string   name;
    int      Exam1;
    int      Exam2;
    int      Exam3;
};
STUDENT S[5];
int main()
{
    ifstream f;
    string buf;
    f.open("data.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        getline(f, S[i].name, ' ');
        f>>S[i].Exam1>>S[i].Exam2>>S[i].Exam3;
        cout<<S[i].name<<" "<<S[i].Exam1<<" "<<S[i].Exam2<<" "<<S[i].Exam3<<endl;

    }
    f.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

with input file `data.txt`:

```
Michael 33 76 81
Brenda 44 79 90
Alex 79 88 70
Brian 82 93 50
Kevin 77 73 80
```

Compiled with `g++`, results in output

```
Michael 33 76 81

Brenda 44 79 90

Alex 79 88 70

Brian 82 93 50

Kevin 77 73 80
sh: pause: command not found
```

I don't understand why you don't, unless you didn't copy my code sample correctly...

Comment: still getting the same thing
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @user3326689 - happy you got it working. What was the fix in the end?

Comment: There was actually a problem with my text file, that's why it only printed zeros. Thanks again!